# ¿Cómo puedo introducir una imagen en un datagridview c# y que esta escale su tamaño al cuadro donde se dispone?

Tags: mysql, c#, windows-forms, windows, datagridview

estoy realizando una app de windows form visual studio 2022 para la realización de ofertas.
las ofretas están en un datagridview donde cada fila es un producto en oferta con sus respectivos campos. uno de estos es una imagen. los datos provienen de base de datos mysql y la imagen de ruta local del ordenador.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
hasta el momento consigo introducir la imagen en la columna foto pero está guarda el tamaño "origina" y no se ve del bien.
para concluir, me gustaria saber si hay alguna forma de darle un tamaño fijo a los cuadros del datagridview y que la imagen que cargo se adapte a su respectivo cuadro.
adjunto imagen de la app y codigo de la carga de datos.

```
  private void cargadatos()
    {

        try
        {

            conectar();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT codigo," +
                " nombre, Id_Familia, precio" +
                " from OFERTAS  ORDER BY Id_Familia, codigo asc;", conn);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(dt);
            dt.Columns.Add("foto", Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"));
            foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
            {
                try
                {              
                    drow["foto"] = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Users\\alexg" +
                             "\\Desktop\\fotos_articulos\\" + drow["codigo"]
                             .ToString() + ".jpg");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                
            }

         dtgvOfertas.RowTemplate.Height = 200;
            
            dtgvOfertas.AutoSizeColumnsMode = 
                DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
            dtgvOfertas.DataSource = dt;
            int numColumnas = dtgvOfertas.ColumnCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < numColumnas; i++)
            {
                dtgvOfertas.Columns[i].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment =
                    DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                dtgvOfertas.Columns[i].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment =
                    DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

            }      
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        desconectar();

    }
```